# white text stand out in the grey background

Tags: html, css

I have a div tag with `background-color: #FFFFFF` and `opacity: 0.08`. Inside it is a span tag with the colour white. What can I do to make the white text stand out in the grey background in the parent div? It seems that i cannot increase parent's opacity

[image]

Comment: You should at least post your HTML markup.

Comment: Change the background-color of the span to black?

Comment: i don t have it right now since i have to write html/css code from an output png image.

Comment: The problem you have is the parent div opacity. It is too low and all its contents will inherit it. Even with a black background for the span it will look light gray. See if you can increase the div's opacity

Comment: the parent opacity is already set to 1

Answer (score 1):

Or you should be able to get this effect by using `rgba()` notation:

```css
div{
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

span {
  color: #fff;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just make it a fairly dark grey:

```css
#background {
  background-color: #222222;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
#text {
  color: #FFFFFF;
  background-color: #444444;
}
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<div id="background" style="height: 100vh; width: 100vw;">
  <span id="text">Ngay Nhap Vien</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use text-shadow as well along with RGBA [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ujce3xnf/)

HTML:

```
<div>
  <span>text</span>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
div {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.08);
}

span {
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 10px black;
  font-size: 30px;
}
```